# Setting the "dim" color for a Dialog

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog

I understand how to set the dim amount for a Dialog. However, I would prefer that the color was a translucent white instead of a translucent black (or is it dark gray?). Any ideas?

Comment: So how did you implement this? I'm also trying to solve this. Please do reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to create white 9-patch drawable. Similar to `panel_background.9.png` drawable (which is black) that can be found at path:

```
 <android-sdk-dir>/platforms/android-#/data/res/drawable-hdpi/panel_background.9.png
```

Let's assume your drawable will be called `white_panel_background.9.png`.

---

**Option 1.**

You can create your custom theme that extends `Theme.Dialog` and overrides `windowBackground` attribute with custom white 9-patch drawable.

```
 <style name="Theme.WhiteDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/white_panel_background</item>  
 </style>
```

And then use this theme in your dialog:

```
Dialog dialog = Dialog(context, R.style.Theme_WhiteDialog);
```

---

**Option 2.**

If you've already created the dialog (with default theme), you still can update its window background:

```
Dialog dialog = ...;
...
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.white_panel_background);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

---

*Note*: you'll need to change text colors from white to black (so its visible on white background).
*Note*: you'll need to do some extra steps for AlertDialog as it uses its own styles for backgrounds. For more details see [`AlertDialog` style](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/styles.xml;h=d7b654e49809cb97a35682754b1394af5c8bc88b;hb=HEAD#l39).

---

[image]

Comment: I'll try this out in the morrow. Does this update the dialog's window background or the dim that covers the screen around the dialog?

Comment: No worries. Any thoughts on the outer dim?

Comment: I've made some investigations, you actually can not emulate "white" dim, as this is hard coded effect in WindowManager. You can make the window to fill whole screen and be white and transparent enough. But this is not animated (by default) and background is not dimmed.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I think I'll just create the effect in my glsurfaceview, or maybe an alphaanimation.